# How to fill the rightmost column with values in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ffill

There is an unknown number of columns, and each row has exactly one value.

However, I cannot tell which column the number is in.

I would like to know how to fill one value from each row into the rightmost column.

The example below consists of three columns, but I don't know how many there actually are.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp = u"""
col1,col2,col3
nan,nan,3
nan,4,nan
1,nan,nan
"""

data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=",")

# data
# Out[31]: 
#    col1  col2  col3
# 0   NaN   NaN   3.0
# 1   NaN   4.0   NaN
# 2   1.0   NaN   NaN


What I want:

# data2
#     col3
# 0    3.0
# 1    4.0
# 2    1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know you have exactly one value in each row, you can add all the rows.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp = u"""
col1,col2,col3
nan,nan,3
nan,4,nan
1,nan,nan
"""

data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=",")
```

---

```
data['col4'] = data.sum(axis=1, numeric_only=True)
```

---

One more way is to :

```
data['col4'] = data.loc[:,[*data.columns.values]].sum(axis=1)
```

Output

[image]

[pandas.DataFrame.sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure there is only one value in each row, you can just sum them over the columns. The NaN's will be ignored.

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

temp = u"""
col1,col2,col3
nan,nan,3
nan,4,nan
1,nan,nan
"""

data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=",")
print(data.sum(axis=1))

0    3.0
1    4.0
2    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

In Pandas you can use the [.bfill()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) method along the `axis=1` to fill in missing values.

you should do something like this:

```py
data2 = data.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1].to_frame()

print(data2)
```

and this should work.

Answer (score 0):

If all values are `NaN` except one on each row, you can also use `max`:

```
>>> data.max(axis=1)
0    3.0
1    4.0
2    1.0
dtype: float64
```

For the same expected output:

```
>>> data.ffill(axis=1)[['col3']]
   col3
0   3.0
1   4.0
2   1.0
```